# Where to write bower code to install Alertify?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, bower, alertify

I am getting started with jquery plugins and I have decided to have a go at Alertify.
I visited the webpage:
http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/

It tells me to install using bower package management. They even give the code for us. 
What I want to know is where to write this code:

```
$ bower install alertify
```

Should I write it in the html file, css file or in the jquery file.

Comment: use Jquery ui dialog http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ it's much better supported.

Comment: So you want every visitor to your site to have to install a plugin???  The method of including it as a script below is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Do you have to do it with bower? I dont think you have to install bower if you go to a site that has alertify?!

Comment: I still havent got the answer to the original question. Does anyone know where to write the bower code?

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use "Inserting into HTML" method written on that site?

Include JS

```
<!-- ideally at the bottom of the page -->
<!-- also works in the <head> -->
<script src="PATH_TO_FILE/alertify.min.js"></script>
```

Include CSS

```
<!-- include the core styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="PATH_TO_FILE/alertify.css" />
<!-- include a theme, can be included into the core instead of 2 separate files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="PATH_TO_FILE/alertify.default.css" />
```

If you want to use Bower, you should use node.js. You can find info about Bower in its [github page](https://github.com/bower/bower).

Comment: So it will work without initially installing with bower? 
ok thank you.but I hope someone will tell me where to put the bower code anyway. You may need it in the future.

Comment: I've edited my post. Just visit github page of Bower. You will find out many interesting things.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you enter that into the command line.
Bower is a package manager that is run from the command line and requires Node and npm. If you are just getting started with jQuery plugins, I think it would be easier to download and include the plugin into your project.